# htaccess image size parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with htaccess and rewriteRule

I want to change the filename if I there is  "w" parameters and it's an image.

> original url : image.jpg?w=500
>
> redirect : image-500.jpg

I tried something like that, but it seems to only remove all the images :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)\.[jpg|png|jpeg|gif]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\-([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$ /$1.$3?w=$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.gif|\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?w=(.*)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.(.*)$ /$1-%2.$2?%1 [R=301,L]
```